# Bootstrap 4 date input to show calendar icon

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I don't like how date input looks in Bootstrap 4. Right now it has two states and when you hover over it, it shows 3 arrows. And one of the arrows is opening calendar.

I want to replace them all with just one calendar icon *(**update1**: but the calendar should be clickable)*, as showed in the picture below.

***update2***: https://jsfiddle.net/wxeg4vk7/

`<input type="date" class="form-control" id="pickupdate">`

How can I achieve that?

[image: bootstrap date picker]

Thank you!

Comment: Can you Please check if [this](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) helps

Answer (score 1):

To start with, hide the default html5 date spinners. Customize then color and position of the date picker-indicator...

```
.form-control[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
.form-control[type=date]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}   

input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateX(16px);
}
```

Finally, use an `input-group`...

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="date">
   <span class="input-group-append ml-n1">
     <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent"><i class="fa fa-calendar-alt"></i></div>
   </span>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/22Kp9X4CAD

Comment: This seems to kill most of the built-in calendar functionality. At least in Chrome

Comment: Yes, @j08691 is right. I still need the functionality of calendar, I just want to replace arrows with the icon and show it all the time.

Comment: Thank you, it's almost good. How can I add `cursor:pointer;` on that? I tried to do it, but it does not cover the whole icon area.

Comment: I used a button instead and added `cursor: pointer;` to the -webkit-calendar-picker-indicator and it seems to work https://codeply.com/p/22Kp9X4CAD

Comment: Sadly, the click only works if you click on the left side first.

Comment: I fixed that issue with z-index

Comment: Oh, no. Looks like it doesn't work if background has a color, or maybe it's something else. This is sad.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your custom CSS:

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

This will remove the up/down arrows.

Here's a Bootstrap 4 pen: https://codepen.io/fraktar/pen/jObWwdz

Comment: I have tried different addons, but they are not perfect. I like the Bootstrap's native calendar date picker, I just want to show it via click on calendar icon and remove the arrows.

Comment: If you can share the exact code you have right now, I will help you modify it. @Ant

Comment: Thank you @Fraktar, I've added jsfiddle link.

Comment: is it possible to have it inside of the input area while giving it `cursor-pointer`? And why did you decide to change it to dateTIMEpicker?